# Unable to setup ScandiPwa theme in my localhost Magento 2

Tags: magento2, theme, pwa, react-js

I am trying to setup ScandiPWA theme in my localhost.
All configuration are setup as per documentation provide [Existing Magento 2 setup](https://docs.scandipwa.com/getting-started-1/magento-integration) but still not show the proper scandipwa theme instead it shows Magento blank theme.

Screenshots:

- Content->Design->Configuration theme was changed [screenshot 1](https://prnt.sc/MYL2GW5pnAvk).
- Problem is not show scnadipwa theme. It's show magento blank theme [screenshot 2](https://prnt.sc/3O3Jhj5jS5VV).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the theme on the first and second item?

[image]

Comment: Yes, also i try to change both store theme change still it show me magento blank theme

Comment: Have you tried doing deploy static commands and cache flush after?

Comment: Yes, i tried s:s:d -f and c:f also, but no effect.